# What is difference b/w http header value set to null using 1.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty and 2. using CURL?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, curl

I want to know difference between 1.http header value set to null using HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty and 2.http header value set to null using CURL.

1.
Using the JAVA code when I set HTTP header value to null as shown below, server side I am observing that Header is removed by server (I have printed all HTTP request header on server side)

Code:

connection.setRequestProperty("test-header", null);

where, connection is instance of HttpURLConnection

2.
Using CURL when I set HTTP header value as null, server side I am observing that test-header actually comes as null

curl command:
curl -v -H "test-header: null" "http://endpoint_I_hit"

server side I actually see test-header=null

Why header is removed in 1. and why header comes with null value in 2.?
what is the correct way to set null value for header using CURL?
Web-server I am running is Apache tomcat 7

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the code here? how did you printed all HTTP request header on server side?

Comment: In cURL, everything is a string; there's no `null` value. To make a header `null` on the Java side, you just don't include it.